# Is "him" Christ, God, or both?

Tags: 2-corinthians

> <sup>14</sup> But thanks be to God, who in Christ always leads us in triumphal procession, and through us spreads the **fragrance of the knowledge of him** everywhere. <sup>15</sup> For we are the aroma of Christ to God among those who are being saved and among those who are perishing, <sup>16</sup> to one a fragrance from death to death, to the other a fragrance from life to life. Who is sufficient for these things? <sup>17</sup> For we are not, like so many, peddlers of God's word, but as men of sincerity, as commissioned by God, in the sight of God we speak in Christ. (2 Corinthians 2 ESV)

Is "him" in verse 14 referring to Christ, God, or both Christ and God?

Answer (score 3):

God, in Christ, spreads the fragrance of the knowledge of him. (Note, not of 'himself' but of 'him'.)

For we are the aroma of Christ - to God.

It is without doubt that the fragrance (of the knowledge of him) is the same as the aroma of him, which is 'we'.

The fragrance is spread 'through us' ... for 'we' are the aroma.

This fragrance (of the knowledge of Christ) is spread (through 'us, in triumphant procession) to others.

Also, this aroma (of Christ) ascends up to God himself. And this is witnessed both by those being saved and by those perishing.

I would suggest that the literal translation of Young is clearer :

> 14 and to God `are' thanks, who at all times is leading us in triumph in the Christ, and the fragrance of His knowledge He is manifesting through us in every place,

> 15 because of Christ a sweet fragrance we are to God, in those being saved, and in those being lost;

> [2 Corinthians 2: 14,15 YLT ]

Answer (score 1):

Paul borrows the images of a Roman triumphal procession:

> 2 Corinthians 2:14 But thanks be to God, who in Christ always leads us in **triumphal procession**, and through us spreads the fragrance of the knowledge of him everywhere.

Pulpit Commentary

> The mental vision of a Roman triumph summons up various images before the mind of St. Paul. He thinks of the streets breathing with the fragrance of incense offered upon many a wayside altar; of the tumult and rejoicing of the people; of the fame and glory of the **conqueror**; of the miserable captives led aside from the funeral procession to die,
> ... The triumph of L. **Mummius** over the conquest of Corinth had been one of the most splendid which the Roman world had ever seen, and in A.D., shortly before this Epistle was written (A.D. 57), **Claudius** had celebrated his triumph over the Britons and their king Caractacus, who had been led in the procession, but whose life had been spared (Tacitus, 'Ann.,' 13:36). The savour of his knowledge; i.e. the fragrance of the knowledge of **Christ**. ...
> Even at that early period, not twenty-five years after the Crucifixion, the gospel had been very widely preached in Asia and Europe (Romans 15:18, 19).

By the time of 2 Corinthians, the gospel has been preached in (or to use Paul's metaphor, has conquered) Asia and Europe. Like Roman conquerors Mummius and Claudius, Paul pictures Christ as the conqueror leading the triumphal procession.

Is "him" in verse 14 referring to Christ, God, or both Christ and God?

The visual image is the human Christ. The deeper meaning is God in Christ.